How do I assign values to this pointer in C
New to C, having trouble figuring out how to edit and access this pointer in a struct
Using this struct
typedef struct student_info {
  char  *first;
  char  *last;
  int   exam1;
  int   exam2;
  int   exam3;
  float mean;
} student;

And trying to write to the first name and last name like so:
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

#include "student.h"
#include "bubble.h"

int main()
{
  //Initial Variable Declaration
  student students[19];

  //Read recurring student info from 'grades'
  for (int i = 0; i < 19; ++i)//check if the loop has to occur dynamically
  {
    //Read first name & last name
    cin >> *(students[i].first) >> *(students[i].last);
  }

  //Output read data to test
  //Output recurring data
  for (int i = 0; i < 19; ++i)
  {
    //Output first and last name ending with a tab
    //cout << students[i].first << "\t" << students[i].last << "\t";
  }

return 0;
}

Getting a segmentation fault error and I cant tell if its a syntax issue with me using these pointers or I'm simply using them completely incorrectly. Would love it if someone could explain the correct way to go about this. Taking a C++ Class and prof basically threw C on me.
I was originally using scanf() and simplified it to cin to make it simpler to troubleshoot for myself but still got the same error. there are other parts to this code but the pointer part of the struct is all I'm having trouble with.

First learn what language you're actually programming in. The shown code is not C.

Pointers first and last are uninitialized, so when you read into them your program will crash.  You probably want to use a buffer (char first[256]) or allocate memory on the fly.  C++ has string support.

You are pulling in a C++ header. Just saying.

ah this is a realloc and malloc situation then I see

As for your problem, *(students[i].first) is the same as students[i].first[0]. So first of all it tries to use the uninitialized pointer, which leads to your crash; Secondly you only try to read a single character, not a string.

And what is your actual assignment? Are you forced to use the structure as shown? What are your requirements? What are your limitations? And just because you have a pointer doesn't mean you need to use malloc, not in C++ anyway. And the first person you should really talk to are the other students in your class, followed by the professor. This site should be no higher than third.

Yes this assignment has that struct given and I have to use it as such @Someprogrammerdude, No one has answered my DM's in the class discord sadly. Still trying to learn how to allocate memory effectively

You went beyond yourself by several steps. I recommend to go back a little and first learn and practice: a) C hello world (i.e. get rid of anything C++, it will only confuse you) b) C input (i.e. into solid variables, not pointers before you know them) c) C pointers to solid variables d) C pointers to dynamically allocated memory . If you feel already confidently familiar with the first one or two start with the first one you do not know. Play with that, learn, pratice. Then add the next one. Based on a decent book (hopefully the text book of your class) that should get you forward. Then ask.

As long as so many things are wobbly in your knowledge, I vote to close this question as lacking focus, because "Fix this multi-broken randomly put together code for  me." is not a question according to [ask].

@Yunnosch See thats the thing my class is all in c++ and prof randomly has us writing this program in C and the next assignment is this again but in c++.

Unless the professor is deranged, she or he must have been going over pointers and dynamic allocation before, or at least pointed out where in your text-books you can read more about it. In C++ you should use new[] to allocate an array of elements (well, you should really use std::string for strings, but if you're limited by the structure as presented you have to work with what you have). Remember that C-style string arrays are really called null-terminated strings. A string of x characters need space for x + 1 characters to be able to fit the terminator.

That is weird and I feel with you. Hopefully there is a decent teaching concept, maybe "C++ class for experienced C programmers". But it does not change anything about the many issue with your code and your question. Pointers in C are one of the parts where C is really different from C++ and you won't get anywhere with doing this with C++ mixed in. Not what the prof wants, Not what would help you. Not what is a decently focused question here.

In order to help you (with your project and with making this a decent question) I recommend to learn and to ask about how in C to read in a text into memory that is allocated to a pointer to char. I.e. leave a lot of the requirements and weirdness of your assignment out and focus on the core of one of the problems. The one slowing you down the most I believe to be the "pointers in C have to actually point to something" part, which is targeted by the question I propose. You can [edit] to remove most of your question and focus accordingly.

Optionally, even more risk free, start with first learning and asking about reading text into a statically defined fixed-length array of characters. Then ask a separate second question about how to change that into something using a pointer to char. (Shed the struct around it for starters.)

My first few comments I realise might come over a little harsh. I hope the total turns out kind and helpful. Good luck anyway.

@Yunnosch not at all, ive gotten way worse on here lol

If you make these changes it will work.
typedef struct student_info {
  char  first[20];
  char  last[20];
  int   exam1;
  int   exam2;
  int   exam3;
  float mean;
} student;

students[i].first instead of *(students[i].first)
If you want to use pointer, you must first initialize it with malloc.

On this line you are trying to dereference undefined pointer, i.e. to the memory that was not allocated:
cin >> *(students[i].first) >> *(students[i].last);

This gives you a segfault.
One way to deal with the problem is to allocate char arrays inside your "student_info" structure as suggested by Ömer YILDIZ:
typedef struct student_info {
  char  first[20];
  char  last[20];
  int   exam1;
  int   exam2;
  int   exam3;
  float mean;
} student;

Note that student_info.first and student_info.last will still be char* in this case.
This approach has two obvious disadvantages:

Excessive memory consumption: 20 chars are allocated for all names, even if they are much shorter
If the program will encounter a name (more likely surname) that is longer than 20 symbols - it'll segfault again
So I would at lest allow cin read only up to 20 characters:

    for (int i = 0; i < 19; ++i)
    {
        cin.getline(student.first, 20);
        cin.getline(student.second, 20);
    }

Dealing with the excessive memory consumption is a little more complicated,so not sure you want to do it in this project. Anyways: allocate a huge temporary buffer first, read into it and count the length of the name, and allocate the desired amount of memory using malloc, don't forget to free it at the end of the program.
